# Javascript (onclick) pop up bigger image window from image array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, popup, onclick

I have an array of images that populate the page and what I am having trouble with is coming up with a way to create an ONCLICK popup image window from the thumbnails (but the popup window needs to be a bigger size image):

here is the js code:

```
var str = "<table>";
var imgFolder = "images/"; 

var cover = new Array();
    cover[0] = "kitchenHouseSale.jpg";
    cover[1] = "eatLive.jpg";
    cover[2] = "loveAnthonySale.jpg";


var coverone = new Array();
    coverone[0] = "casualVacancy.jpg";
    coverone[1] = "quiet.jpg";
    coverone[2] = "whirlAway.jpg";

var covertwo = new Array();
    covertwo[0] = "everyLastSale.jpg";
    covertwo[1] = "neilYoung.jpg";
    covertwo[2] = "soupSisters.jpg";

var title = new Array();
    title[0] = "The Kitchen House";
    title[1] = "Eat to Live";
    title[2] = "Love Anthony";

for (var i = 0; i < cover.length; i++)
{
   str += "<tr><td colspan='2'><h2>" + category[i] + "</h2></td></tr>";
   str += "<tr><td class='basket'><img src='" + imgFolder + cover[i] + "' width='108'    height='159'>
}

str += "</table>";
var elem = document.getElementById("table");
elem.innerHTML = str;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First-of-all create a popup layout in html and set display none like this:-

```css
.popUp{
    display:none
    // other CSS properties
}
```

```html
<div class='popUp'>
    // Your content here
</div>
```

You have to create an on-click function on the the spot where you want to click and display the pop-up. And you must pass the button or dom element you are clicking within the function like this:

```js
onclick(myFtn(this));
```

Create a button tag outside the image and wrap the image into it. And add `onclick` event on it like shown above.

Your function will look like this:

```js
function myFtn(imageBtn){
    let popUpCont=  document.querySelector('.popUp');
    let image = imgaeBtn.querySelector('image');  //This will select you image
    let imageSrc = image.src;
    let popImage = documnent.createElement('img')
    popImage.src = imageSrc;
    popImage.alt = 'Example Image';
    popImage.width = 300; //Your image width
    popImage.height = 200; // Your image height
    popUpCont.style.display='block'
    popUpCont.appendChild(popImage);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a good start. There is a more complete example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Do i get you right? You want the user to click on an image and a bigger version of the same image is supposed to appear in a popup-window?

Have a look at window.open() then: http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
You must specify the absolute path of the image - file as the url for the popup, like http://your.domain.com/images/kitchenHouseSale.jpg.

you can then add an onclick-handler to the img-tag, something like this:

```
<img src='" + imgFolder + cover[i] + "' width='108'    height='159' onclick="window.open('http://your.domain.com + this.src)" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, it works for the first image but since I have them grouped in arrays as cover, coverone and covertwo, the code does not work for each image (under the cover array and under coverone array and so on). Anyway to go about it? Not sure if this is clear. thank you!!